# Question on big O notation for two small parameters of the same order

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have two small parameters $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in some perturbation problem: $0< \epsilon <<1$ and $0<\delta<<1$, with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ the same order of magnitude, $\epsilon = O(\delta)$. Is it correct to state

$$\frac{\epsilon}{\delta} = c$$

Where $c$ is some constant, with $c = O(1)$?

Comment: $c$ cannot depend on your parameters, but you can use $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to find a bound.

Comment: Is it correct to state that $\epsilon$ is a constant multiple of $\delta$? Would it be completely correct to restate the perturbation problem so that there is only one small parameter, $0 < \delta \ll 1$, and replace all occurrences of $\epsilon$ with $c\delta$? My hunch is that this is not OK (that if you could really use only $\delta$, the problem would already have been written that way), but maybe there's something about your particular perturbation problem that allows it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about your comments. It's my own problem, in fact - so I am indeed already thinking if I can restate it in terms one parameter @DavidK

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct. It is correct that $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta} \le c$ for some constant $c$.

The assertion "Where $c$ is some constant, with $c = O(1)$?" is redundant. Any constant is automatically $O(1)$.

You could say that  $\epsilon/\delta = O(1) $  though.